# How to pass bash array to python script

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I just started learning bash script,slowly making hands dirty. I have a roadblock while passing the bash array to the python script.

```
export arr=(val val val)
value=$(python script.py "${arr[@]}")
```

I'm getting nothing passed to python script.

```
for i in sys.argv[1:]:
    print(i)
```

Output got in Python:

script.py

Expected Output in Python:

```
 val
 val 
 val
```

Comment: Side note: You don't need to export the array.

Comment: It works as expected for me.

Comment: @Barmar I tried without export also but nothing is passing.

Comment: It works for me both ways.

Comment: Your bash version?

Comment: What do you see if you just do `echo "${arr[@]}"`?

Comment: 3.2.57, because I'm on a Mac

Comment: @Barmar It's just because my array is like this arr=(country (US, $Dollar), India Rupee ,British Pound)

Comment: What's because of that?

Comment: Bash arrays don't use commas between the elements. And you can't have nested arrays.

Comment: I used `arr=(val val val)` in my test, like you show in the question.

Comment: I just tested it in bash 5.0.3 on Linux, it also worked as expected.

Comment: What does `declare -p arr` print?

Comment: I'm getting  " country (US," in python which

Comment: @jessy Please be sure you're executing *exactly* the code in the question (or the same with `export` removed). I'm pretty sure part of the confusion here is a difference between what's in the question and what you're actually doing.